# Finite algebraic variety of projective space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space

I came across this theorem (which I didn't understand) in Algebraic geometry by Harris.
Suppose $F$ is a subset of $\mathbb{P}^n$ (projective space of dimension $n$) containing $d<2n$ points in general position. Then $F$ can be described as the zero locus of quadratic polynomials.
I am new at algebraic geometry so any clear step by step argument is appreciated.

Comment: What part did you not understand in Harris? What background do you have? Do you know what it means to say that points are in general position? Do you know cohomology?

Comment: Doesn't he prove this? Could you be more specific about which part doesn't make sense to you?

Comment: First of all I did't get what is meant by points in general position.Second why the point q(as described in the book) has to be in one of the hyperplane(It seems to me he never used the fact we are dealing with variety of some quadratic polynomials)

Comment: Not all of us have Harris' book available. Could you copy his proof, so perhaps someone can explain it?

Answer (score 3):

This is theorem 1.4 in Harris.  The term *general position* is defined immediately above the theorem.

Now, by assumption $q$ is a point such that every quadratic polynomial $f$ which vanishes at each point of $\Gamma$ also vanishes at $q$.  Since $\Gamma$ consists of $2n$ points in general position, the first $n$ points span a hyperplane $\Lambda_1$ and the other $n$ points span a hyperplane $\Lambda_2$.

Write $f_1$ for the linear polynomial cutting out $\Lambda_1$ and $f_2$ for the linear polynomial cutting out $\Lambda_2$.  Then $f = f_1 f_2$ is a quadratic polynomial which vanishes precisely on $\Lambda_1$ and $\Lambda_2$.  In particular, $f$ vanishes at each point of $\Gamma$.  By assumption, this means $f$ also vanishes at $q$.  So it follows that $q$ lies on either $\Lambda_1$ or $\Lambda_2$.